# Solving problems regarding accessing localhost over LAN

Tags: apache, windows-7, lan

I have two computers with IP addresses of 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 respectively. Both computers have Apache servers installed on them and both are listening to port 8080 rather than 80. I have connected both computers via LAN and I am successful in pinging each other. However, I am unable to access localhost of one computer on the other.

What are the required settings that should be altered??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IP address 127.0.0.1 is a special loopback address commonly known as localhost. It aways refers to the machine you are currently on. It's best practice not to use the 127.0.0.0/8 netblock for addressing anything other than the local machine.

The LAN you describe to also has 192.186.1.1 and 192.186.1.2 bound to each machine respectively. Use this to communicate with each machine.
e.g. from 192.186.1.1, enter http://192.186.1.2:8080/ to see the other machine.

When using names, like "localhost", your [Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) is used to resolve the name to an IP address, falling back onto DNS. On most systems, this behaviour can also be modified.

The above assumes you have no firewalls or special routing in place.

Comment: +1. But on Windows 7 and up; the localhost resolution is built into the DNS resolver itself, so the hosts file doesn't even get used for localhost resolution, which is why it's commented out on Windows 7.

Comment: I have made sure that firewall isn't the problem.

Comment: I have switched off the firewall but this is still not helping

Comment: As we're using IP addresses, the DNS doesn't matter - useful knowing about Windows 7's resolution special case for **localhost** though.

Answer (score 3):

localhost is used to access the same computer from itself only. localhost always resolves to the local ip 127.0.0.1

To access one computer from another you have to use the ip address such as 192.16.8.1.1 or 192.168.1.2

Comment: Yeah I tried it like this: 192.168.1.2:8080 but things aren't working like this.

Comment: @Spoilt: what *exactly* does "things aren't working" mean? Any errors? What *does* happen? Oh, and btw, is perhaps your firewall on one or both machines blocking incoming connections?

Comment: The progress bar of the browser goes on for ever.....and I tried to ping but all in vain.

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` is an alias for the local address 127.0.0.1; it *always* means "this *local host* right here", so that's expected behavior.

You can access them either by their IP addresses, add each other's hostname to their `hosts` file, or set up a small DNS server.

Comment: so when both have same IPs for the localhost, something link 127.0.X.X, what should I do to make ot work??

Comment: @Spoilt: Well of course they do - the IP address for localhost is *always* from the 127.0.0.0/8 range (usually 127.0.0.1); that's the local computer address, and you can't reach any other computer on it, only the *local* one. As for "what to do" - did you see the second paragraph of my answer? Try accessing them at http://192.168.1.1/ and http://192.168.1.2/ , respectively.

Comment: Well I tried it like this: 192.168.1.2:8080 but its not working. Can you explain a bit on the DNS servers. I have no idea how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

If you are on machine 192.168.1.1 and are trying to connect to port 8080 on 192.168.1.2, where ping 192.168.1.2 works but opening http://192.168.1.2:8080/ doesn't, try:

```
telnet 192.168.1.2 8080
```

It shouldn't respond with connection refused, but instead **Connect to: ...**. From there enter:

```
GET /
```

If I do that for **telnet www.google.com 80** an hit enter:

```
Trying 173.194.67.105...
Connected to www.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.co.uk/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=562c9df87033be9d:FF=0:TM=1325703914:LM=1325703914:S=eV6aBcXk3LTKVwxB; expires=Fri, 03-Jan-2014 19:05:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Date: Wed, 04 Jan 2012 19:05:14 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 221
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.uk/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Failing that can you provide:

- Operating system of both machines
- The error you get in what browser when you try the web address
- The full output for **telnet www.google.com 80** and **telnet 192.168.1.2 8080**, as above.